# More fields in a database or more records?

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

I'm making a database for different rental investments for my employer. I want each record to have the investment code followed by expected monthly cashflows for the next 10 years.

I can set this up with 120 fields for each future monthly cashflow,

OR

I have only 3 fields - investment code, month and cashflow.

Which is better? I will probably have 5000 new investments each month. The first produces 5000 records, the second produces 600000. Is that a problem? I'll want to run queries and stuff based on relationships in the rest of the database. Which approach gives the best performance?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: any way is ok. The question is which is faster or more organised? That will depend on what kind of queries are you making -- but generally people create relational tables so they split things up to look more organised and avoid data repetiton

Answer (score 0):

I like the second approach, it might have bigger table size as the investment code repeats for each record, however is more normalized. I dont think there should be any performance issue if you have proper primary keys setup. It also has another advantage for new investments: you dont need to have 120 fields as they seem to start at any month.

Comment: It is not more normalized. Normalization replaces a table by smaller tables that join to it, hence using the same column names. It's just a "better" design. Because it allows us to write queries that return different numbers of monthly cashflows without having to hardwire that many subexpressions into our queries.

Answer (score 0):

An update...

I did my own testing using both the wide and short vs narrow and tall options using a test of many thousands.

The query performance of both is roughly the same (as long as the query is well designed and doesn't return individual records). If you use a stopwatch, the wider table is slightly better by a couple of seconds, but tall is still acceptable.

The main difference is the amount of data produced. Wide takes up only 200mb. Tall takes up 1gb for the same information! Writing data in tall takes a lot longer.

Given that Access has a 2gb limit, and that I don't need the flexibility to ever add past 5 years worth (I know for a fact this will not be needed), I think I'll go with option 1 - short and wide tables.

I'm a little surprised a just how big the tall table was - I would have though Access would be able to compress data a little better.